# Android Data is repeating in my spinner while switching between activities

Tags: android, json, spinner

Below is the code where i m parsing JSON and this method gets called onResume() method.

```
    private void parseJSONSubTypeEventsSelect(String response)
                throws JSONException {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray columns = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");
            JSONArray rowsWrapper = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");

            JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();

            List<List<String>> listOfListRow = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < rowsWrapper.length(); i++) {

                    if (i == rowsWrapper.length()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        map.put(rowsWrapper.get(i).toString(),jsonHelper.toList(rowsWrapper.getJSONArray(i)));
                        rowListSubTypeEvents = jsonHelper.toList(rowsWrapper.getJSONArray(i));
                        listOfListRow.add(rowListSubTypeEvents);
                    }
                }

                // System.out.println(listOfListRow);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am Clearing the data here but the same data is printed twice

```
                StandName.clear();
                slNo.clear();
                Rate.clear();

                System.out.println("StandName before"+StandName);
                System.out.println("slNo before"+slNo);
                System.out.println("Rate before"+Rate);

                StandName.add("Select Stand Name");
                slNo.add("");
                Rate.add("");

                System.out.println("StandName after"+StandName);
                System.out.println("slNo after"+slNo);
                System.out.println("Rate after"+Rate);

                for (List<String> listRows : listOfListRow) {
                    int k = 0;
                    for (String value : listRows) {

                        k++;
                        switch (k) {

                        case 1:
                            imageMapCoords.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileNameList);
                            break;

                        case 2:

                            slNo.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileName1List);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            StandName.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileName1List);
                            break;
                        case 4:

                            Rate.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileName1List);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            avail.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileName1List);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            allowSeatSelection.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileName1List);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            panaromicView.add(value);
                            // listOfListRow.add(logoFileName1List);
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                }
                tvVenue.setText(Venue.get(Venue.size() - 1));

                System.out.println("Stand names from third activity"+StandName);


                System.out.println("data sending to pojo slNo "+slNo);
                System.out.println("data sending to pojo StandName"+StandName);
                System.out.println("data sending to pojo Rate"+Rate);
                for (int i = 0; i <= rowsWrapper.length(); i++) {
                    RowItemThird item = new RowItemThird(slNo.get(i),StandName.get(i), Rate.get(i));
                    rowItems.add(item);

                }


                adapter = new CustomBaseAdapterThird(this, rowItems);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // lvThird.setAdapter(adapter);

                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


                pDialog.hide();
                pDialog.dismiss();

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        positionCheckStandName = StandName.get(position);

                        System.out.println("positionCheckStandName"+positionCheckStandName);

                        positionSlNo = slNo.get(position);
                        stringRate = Rate.get(position);



                        System.out.println("SLNO"+positionSlNo);

                /*      spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();*/



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {



                    }

                });
```

Below is the pojo class

```
    public class RowItemThird {

        private String mSlNo;
        private String mStandName;
        private String mRate;

        public RowItemThird(String slNo, String StandName, String Rate) {
            mSlNo = slNo;
            mStandName = StandName;
            mRate = Rate;
        }

        public String getmSlNo() {
            return mSlNo;
        }

        public void setmSlNo(String mSlNo) {
            this.mSlNo = mSlNo;
        }

        public String getmStandName() {
            return mStandName;
        }

        public void setmStandName(String mStandName) {
            this.mStandName = mStandName;
        }

        public String getmRate() {
            return mRate;
        }

        public void setmRate(String mRate) {
            this.mRate = mRate;
        }



    }
```

Below is the BaseAdapter class to add items to spinner

```
    public class CustomBaseAdapterThird extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context mContext;
        private List<RowItemThird> mRowItems;

        TextView slNO;
        TextView StandName;
        TextView Rate;

        public CustomBaseAdapterThird(Context context, List<RowItemThird> rowItems)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mRowItems = rowItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mRowItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return mRowItems.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return mRowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = null;

            LayoutInflater mInflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.event_list_item_third_sub_type_event_select, null);

            slNO = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSLNo);
            StandName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStand);    
            Rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRate);

            RowItemThird row = (RowItemThird) getItem(position);

            slNO.setText(row.getmSlNo());       
            StandName.setText(row.getmStandName());
            Rate.setText(row.getmRate());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are adding the data to the `rowItems` object, which you are passing to the spinner adapter

```
 adapter = new CustomBaseAdapterThird(this, rowItems);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So clear the ``rowItems` data before adding the new data

```
 rowItems.clear();
 for (int i = 0; i <= rowsWrapper.length(); i++) {
                    RowItemThird item = new RowItemThird(slNo.get(i),StandName.get(i), Rate.get(i));
                    rowItems.add(item);

                }
```